# Spring Batch Flow - Getting Next State Not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

So I feel like I've properly defined my job flow but when I run it I am getting a FlowExecutionException saying that my 'Next state not found in flow' for flow 'd'.

I am using a tasklet that implements a JobExecutionListener as follows which appears to be working as intended:

```
  @Override
  public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    if(a && b) {
      return new ExitStatus("a");
    } else if(c) {
      return new ExitStatus("b");
    } else if(d) {
      return new ExitStatus("c");
    } else {
      return new ExitStatus("d");
    }
  }
```

Here is my job configuration. I would also like to simplify it (all steps are going to 'b' so I would like that to be an 'after' kind of thing) but just want it to work first.

```
  @Bean
  public Job job() {
    LOGGER.info("STARTING BATCH JOB");
    return jobs.get("job")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(taskletStep())
        .on("a")
            .to(step1a)
            .next(step2)
        .on("b")
            .to(step2)
        .on("c")
            .to(step2)
        .on("d")
            .to(step1b)
            .next(step2)
        .on("*").end()
        .end()
        .build();
  }
```

I know that I must be missing some part of the flow but I can't pinpoint it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. I need to use the 'from' function to let my configuration know where I am using 'on' from (it currently thinks I am looking for an exit status on 'step2' for each. So it would look like so:

```
  @Bean
  public Job job() {
    LOGGER.info("STARTING BATCH JOB");
    return jobs.get("job")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(taskletStep())
        .on("a")
            .to(step1a)
            .next(step2)
        .from(taskletStep())            
        .on("b")
            .to(step2)
        .from(taskletStep()) 
        .on("c")
            .to(step2)
        .from(taskletStep()) 
        .on("d")
            .to(step1b)
            .next(step2)
        .end()
        .build();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful, i add one note, it's not JobExecutionListener but StepExecutionListener